# How to read large file to chunk and process it

Tags: java, multithreading

I try to read large file into 10 chunks of FIFO queue in java. each chunk contain 1 GB. if read until 10 chunks. It wait for a while to process. it process each 5 chunks by multi thread. If some thread finish it will pull next chunk to process and then write it to another file. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Just dropping requirements "this is what I want" isn't appreciated. When you try something yourself, and you get stuck with a specific problem, we will gladly help. But please understand that this place is not intended to give guidance with the possibly many steps required to get you from your vision to a working program. In other words: you can do that by starting to try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are clear that you are going to read 10 GB file, just read the whole thing sequentially as DISK I/O is pretty slow, unless you know that your production grade machine has some SSD and things are super fast.

Assuming the file is a text file, use FileInputStream > InputStreamReader > BufferedInputStream.